# How to handle posts with IdentityServer3 as authentication server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

### TL;DR

How do you POST data in an ASP.NET MVC project (form, jQuery, [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)), using IdentityServer3 as the authentication server. Also, what flow to use, to make this work?

#### What I'm experiencing

I have a working IdentityServer3 instance. I also have an ASP.NET MVC project. Using hybrid flow, as I will have to pass the user's token to other services. The authentication itself works - when the pages are only using GET. Even if the authenticated user's tokens are expired, something in the background redirects the requests to the auth. server, and the user can continue it's work, without asking the user to log in again. (As far as I understand, the hybrid flow can use refresh tokens, so I assume that's how it can re-authenticate the user. Even if `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated=false`)

For testing purposes, I set the `AccessTokenLifetime`, `AuthorizationCodeLifetime` and `IdentityTokenLifetime` values to 5 seconds in the auth. server. As far as I know, the refresh token's expire time measured in days, and I did not change the default value.

But when I try to use POST, things get "ugly".

- Using form POST, with expired tokens, the request gets redirected to IdentityServer3. It does it's magic (the user gets authenticated) and redirects to my page - as a GET request... I see the `response_mode=form_post` in the URL, yet the posted payload is gone.
- Using axios POST, the request gets redirected to IdentityServer3, but fails with at the pre-flight OPTIONS request.
- Using the default jQuery POST, got same error. (Even though, the default jQuery POST uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to solve the pre-flight issue.)

**startup.cs**

```
  const string authType = "Cookies";

  // resetting Microsoft's default mapper
  JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

  // ensure, that the MVC anti forgery key engine will use our "custom" user id
  AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = "sub";

  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
    AuthenticationType = authType
  });

  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
  {
    ClientId = clientId,
    RedirectUri = adminUri,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = adminUri,
    Authority = idServerIdentityEndpoint,
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = authType,
    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    Scope = "openid profile roles email offline_access",

    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
      #region Handle automatic redirect (on logout)

      RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
      {
        // if signing out, add the id_token_hint
        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType ==
              OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
        {
          var token = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst(idTokenName);
          if (token != null)
          {
            var idTokenHint =
              token.Value;
            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint;
          }
        }
      },

      #endregion

      AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
      {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("AuthorizationCodeReceived " + n.ProtocolMessage.ToString());

        // fetch the identity from authentication response
        var identity = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

        // exchange the "code" token for access_token, id_token, refresh_token, using the client secret
        var requestResponse = await OidcClient.CallTokenEndpointAsync(
          new Uri(idServerTokenEndpoint),
          new Uri(adminUri),
          n.Code,
          clientId,
          clientSecret
        );

        // fetch tokens from the exchange response
        identity.AddClaims(new []
        {
          new Claim("access_token", requestResponse.AccessToken), 
          new Claim("id_token", requestResponse.IdentityToken), 
          new Claim("refresh_token", requestResponse.RefreshToken)
        });

        // store the refresh_token in the session, as the user might be logged out, when the authorization attribute is executed
        // see OrganicaAuthorize.cs
        HttpContext.Current.Session["refresh_token"] = requestResponse.RefreshToken;

        // get the userinfo from the openId endpoint
        // this actually retreives all the claims, but using the normal access token
        var userInfo = await EndpointAndTokenHelper.CallUserInfoEndpoint(idServerUserInfoEndpoint, requestResponse.AccessToken); // todo: userinfo

        if (userInfo == null) throw new Exception("Could not retreive user information from identity server.");

        #region Extract individual claims

        // extract claims we are interested in
        var nameClaim = new Claim(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.Name,
          userInfo.Value<string>(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.Name)); // full name
        var givenNameClaim = new Claim(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.GivenName,
          userInfo.Value<string>(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.GivenName)); // given name
        var familyNameClaim = new Claim(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName,
          userInfo.Value<string>(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName)); // family name
        var emailClaim = new Claim(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.Email,
          userInfo.Value<string>(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.Email)); // email
        var subClaim = new Claim(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.Subject,
          userInfo.Value<string>(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.Subject)); // userid

        #endregion

        #region Extract roles
        List<string> roles;
        try
        {
          roles = userInfo.Value<JArray>(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.Role).Select(r => r.ToString()).ToList();
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException) // if there is only 1 item
        {
          roles = new List<string> { userInfo.Value<string>(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.Role) };
        }
        #endregion

        // attach the claims we just extracted
        identity.AddClaims(new[] { nameClaim, givenNameClaim, familyNameClaim, subClaim, emailClaim });
        // attach roles
        identity.AddClaims(roles.Select(r => new Claim(Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client.JwtClaimTypes.Role, r.ToString())));

        // update the return value of the SecurityTokenValidated method (this method...)
        n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
          identity,
          n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
      },
      AuthenticationFailed = async n => 
      {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("AuthenticationFailed " + n.Exception.ToString());
      },
      MessageReceived = async n =>
      {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("MessageReceived " + n.State.ToString());
      },
      SecurityTokenReceived = async n =>
      {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("SecurityTokenReceived " + n.State.ToString());
      },
      SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
      {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("SecurityTokenValidated " + n.State.ToString());
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured cookie authentication middleware in the MVC app? After the authentication with identity server, an authentication cookie should be set. When the authentication cookie is set and valid IdentityServer redirection will not occur until the cookie expires/deleted.

**Update 1:**

Ok, I misunderstood the quesion. It is logical to redirect to identity server when session times out. It won't work with post payload. You can try doing something like follows.

1. If the request is a normal post, redirect user again to the form
   fill page.
2. If request is ajax post, return unauthorized result and based on
   that response refresh the page from javascript.

Anyway I don't think you will be able to keep the posted data unless you are designing your own solution for that. (e.g keep data stored locally).

But you might be able to avoid this scenario altogether if you carefuly decide identity server's session timeout and your app's session timeout.

In `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` set `UseTokenLifetime = false` that will break connection between identity token's lifetime and cookie session lifetime.

In `CookieAuthenticationOptions` make sliding expiration

   `SlidingExpiration = true,
   ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50),`

Now you are incontrol of your apps session lifetime. Adjust it to match your needs and security conserns.

Comment: Yes, cookie authentication is working. Most probably, that is the reason, that expired users are still re-authenticated. During debugging, I can check HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, and it is false. Yet, when I hit Continue, the user gets redirected to IdentityServer3, I see the default "Please wait..." page, and get redirected back to my site. But always with a GET request.

Comment: just guessing, is AuthenticationType = "Cookies" and SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies" both point to same string. If you can post your startup.cs code it will help to solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, they are both the same. See attached code. (I only included the authType constant. All other variable names are used the same way.)

Comment: I modified the answer. HTH.

Comment: Thank you. Had a feeling, that the POST wont work...
I'll modify my code following your suggestions, and check the behavior of the authentication flow.